# Setting focus to a textbox control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

If I want to set the focus on a textbox when the form is first opened, then at design time, I can set it's tabOrder property to 0 and make sure no other form control has a tabOrder of 0.

If I want to achieve the same result at run-time, using code, how should I proceed?
Are there alternatives to using tabOrder?
I assume any run-time code will be in the form's constructor or its onload event handler?

---

**EDIT**
In other words I'd like to be able to type straight into the textbox as soon as the form appears without having to manually tab to it, or manually select it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Because you want to set it when the form loads, you have to first .Show() the form before you can call the .Focus() method.  The form cannot take focus in the Load event until you show the form

```
Private Sub RibbonForm1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Me.Show()
    TextBox1.Select()
End Sub
```

Comment: how to use focus() method for button or dropdownlist?

Comment: Same! i.e. `ComboBox.Focus()` or `Button1.Focus()`

Answer (score 13):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
textBox1.Select();
```

in the constructor. (This is in C#. Maybe in VB that would be the same but without the semicolon.)

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx :

> Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control
>   authors. Instead, application programmers should use the **Select** method
>   or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate
>   method for forms.

Answer (score 11):

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    TextBox1.Select()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Focus method

```
  Private Sub frmTest_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       yourControl.Focus()
    End Sub
```

Comment: He doesn't want it on page load

Answer (score 1):

To set focus,

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

Set the TabIndex by

```
Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
```

Comment: He doesn't want it on page load

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple :

For the tab control, you need to handle the **_SelectedIndexChanged** event:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged

If TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name = "TabPage1" Then
    TextBox2.Focus()
End If
If TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name = "TabPage2" Then
    TextBox4.Focus()
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the appropriate event handler to use is "Shown".
And you only need to focus the appropriate text box.

```
Private Sub Me_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    myTextbox.Focus()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

create a textbox:

```
 <TextBox Name="tb">
 ..hello..
</TextBox>
```

focus()  ---> it is used to set input focus to the textbox control

```
tb.focus()
```