# Set Focus to Form After Me.Show

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, focus

I've come across a peculiar focusing issue. I have created the following "search" program:

1. It runs in the background.
2. When you double-tap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key it becomes visible.
3. You can type in the textbox because the form has focus.
4. If the form loses focus (I click on my desktop, for example), it disappears after 3 seconds.
5. I double-tap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key again, and again it becomes visible.
6. But this time, no matter what I try, the form is not focused and I cannot type in the textbox without first manually clicking on the form.

What's particularly interesting is that when I run this program in debug mode from Visual Studios, the program regains focus upon double-tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and becoming visible, and I can immediately start typing in the text box. However, when I build this program and run it alone, the program appears but does not regain focus upon double-tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and therefore I cannot type in the text box until I manually click the form.

After Me.Show() I have tried:

- Me.Focus()
- Me.Validate()
- Me.Select()
- Textbox1.Select()
- Textbox1.Focus()

The form is topmost and normally running in administrator, but the same problem arises regardless.

The issue can be recreated in a more simple manner. Create a form with

- Button ("Button1")
- TextBox
- Two timers ("hideForm", "showForm") both with intervals of 1000

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    hideForm.Start()
    sender.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub hideForm_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles hideForm.Tick
    Me.Hide()
    hideForm.Stop()
    showForm.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub showForm_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles showForm.Tick
    showForm.Stop()
    Me.Show()
    Me.Activate()
End Sub
End Class
```

Click the button, and immediately click on a different window (so the form loses focus). Wait until the form is hidden and shown again. The textbox should have focus. Try typing.

**If the program is run in debugging mode in Visual Studios, it works as expected. If you build the program and run it outside of VS, the form will reappear without focus, and you cannot type in the textbox without manually selecting the form.**

Sorry for the long-winded explanation. It's a difficult issue to properly describe.

Comment: You are trying to violate a very basic Windows usability rule, you cannot push a window into the user's face when he's interacting with another one.  Pressing the CTRL key convinces the OS that it is the current window that needs to stay in focus.  You are going to have to do this differently, google "winforms hot key" for basic hits.  NotifyIcon is another standard solution.

Comment: @HansPassant Hey, thanks for the feedback. Also noteworthy, if the program had focus when I called `Me.Hide`, it will forcibly steal focus back upon `Me.Show`, but this wont work if the application didn't have focus upon using `Me.Hide`. I'll check out some of the other options, but the idea of this program is to be able to perform tasks without using the mouse. I'll see what I can find. When you hit the Windows key the start menu steals focus. That's exactly what I'm trying for.

Answer (score 1):

Try the form event handler `Activate`. Inside that method, you can use `setFocus` to gain focus for that particular Text Box. I know this answer is too late. But hope this helps someone.

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an event handler for `Form_Activate`, and within that handler pass the focus to your textbox.

Instead of `Focus`, you can also try `TextBox1.Select`. [This SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294248/setting-focus-to-a-textbox-control) provides some additional information and something about the difference between `Focus` and `Select`.

Comment: I have now tried that. Under "Form1_Activated" I used Textbox1.Focus(), but no luck. The textbox is appears to be selected alright (blue border), but the form itself is not, and therefore not accepting key presses.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the event does in fact trigger, but the form is definitely not focused, as key presses still get passed to whatever I focused on prior to the form showing, whether that be this internet browser or my desktop, ect. and the form's title bar is not the right color to indicate a form with focus.

Comment: @Timothy: Added another option and a useful link.

Comment: `Form.Activate` occurs when the form _receives_ focus. Try `Form.Show` instead.

Comment: @VisualVincent Hello and thank you for the response. I've now tried using `Focus` and `Select` and I've tried them under both `Form.Show` and `Form.Activated`

Comment: @AJD Hey, thanks. I've checked out the link. The textbox is being selected which is great, but unfortunately the form itself is not. It loads topmost and is visible, but it not accepting user input in the form of key presses until I manually click on the form.

Comment: @Timothy : Did you try calling `Me.Activate()` in the `Form.Shown` event?

Comment: @VisualVincent I did indeed.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried (and worked for me), was to set the `Focus()` of the Textbox in the event handler `Shown()` [VB]:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Me.Textbox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

Note: the `Select()` method just didn't do the job. I hope this helps anyone else that comes with this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Textbox you want to assign a focus to in the Design View Window.
Under the Properties window, set the `TabIndex` to 0 (zero).

I didn't even have to use the `TextBox1.Focus()` command. It still bothers me that the `TabIndex` overrides the Focus command.